# Is there a way to dynamically query the database

Tags: android-room

We want to build a filter for a room database, where the filter options are selected by the user.

i.e. 
we have an entity with field (id, name, date, type)
the user may filter a list by date between and/or name contain text and/or type equals something

Is there a way to do this in room?

Comment: I think you have to go the old-fashioned route: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[])

Comment: That is kinda of a solution, thanks CommonsWare

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically query the room database at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51911228/7594961)

Comment: Hey Anees.  I figured this out after google io 18.  But thank you for leaving a comment, good reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that this is not currently possible in the way you want.

I have managed to do it by using the `db.query(query, values)` method. Generate your your query string at runtime (with placeholders `'?'`), and pass an array of runtime generated values. Note that this will return a `Cursor`, not an instance of the specific object you want, so you will have to define a method for mapping the `Cursor` to a POJO.

I've attached some links to my Cursor2Pojo Mapper and an project implementing it. Feel free to use it, as it should solve your problem in a somewhatgraceful manner. It supports list and single instance returns, although requires you add more annotations to your class (Room annotations are class bound so you cannot get them through reflection at runtime)

[Cursor2Pojo custom lib](https://github.com/jackfrancisdalton/LiteratureAnalyser/tree/master/cursor2pojo/src/main/java/jackfrancisdalton/com/cursor2pojo)

[Project Implementation at line 66 - 72](https://github.com/jackfrancisdalton/LiteratureAnalyser/blob/master/app/src/main/java/jackfrancisdalton/com/LiteratureAnalyser/service/RunTimeGeneratedQueryService.java)

Comment: Damn, it would be great to be able to define table dynamically within the annotation @Query("..."). Anyway, thank you for the tips!

Comment: No problems. They are actually working on it now so it is only a matter of time :D

Comment: @andrea.rinaldi It is actually possible. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51911228/7594961).

Comment: Yeah @Anees, they added the annotation a few months after I posted the question! Thanks for integrating :)