# How can I construct SQL query with dynamic column name in room persistent library

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

This doesn't work, and I'm not sure if I wore it wrong or if it's a limitation of Android's Room

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE :column IN (:values)")
fun getByFieldName(column: String, vararg values: String): Flowable<List<FooBar>>
```

Comment: Room simply augments SQLite's placeholder system, and in SQLite, AFAIK, you cannot make a column name be a placeholder.

Comment: Room do **compile time** checking. I don't think you can do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically query the room database at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287465/how-to-dynamically-query-the-room-database-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

@user3063925, Your question is in limitation of Room Library,

But don't worry,

> We can write fully dynamic query on Room Database by using the
>   [`@query()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String))

```
String mQuery = "SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE columnName1 IN ('value_1','value_2') and columnName2 In('value_3','value_4')";

AppDatabase appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
        AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();

Cursor mCursor = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(context).getOpenHelper().getReadableDatabase().query(myQuery);
```

Now you can convert cursor row wise data to your POJO class.