# Doesn't the dynamically query the room database support LiveData?

Tags: android, android-room

I have read the [artical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287465/how-to-dynamically-query-the-room-database-at-runtime/51911228).

Room supports `@RawQuery` annotation to construct queries at run-time, such as Code A.

If I use Code B, I get Error B when I complie it.

It seems that `@RawQuery` doesn't support to return `LiveData`, right?

**Code A**

```
interface DBVoiceDao{ 

   @RawQuery
   fun  runtimeQuery(sortQuery: SupportSQLiteQuery): List<MVoice>
    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
interface DBVoiceDao{ 

   @RawQuery
   fun  runtimeQuery(sortQuery: SupportSQLiteQuery): LiveData<List<MVoice>>
    ...
}
```

**Error B**

```
Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
public abstract class DBVoiceDatabase extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase {
                ^[WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it does support it, but you have to specify the observed entity, as described here
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery example:

```kotlin
@Dao
 interface RawDao {
   @RawQuery(observedEntities = Song.class)
   LiveData<List<Song>> getSongs(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
 }
```