# How To Dynamically Query For Tables Enteries In Database Using Room

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, android-room, android-mvvm

I'm new to Room lib, I'd like to know how I can dynamically select a table from a database in my query.
I have a database that has 10 different tables. Depending on users' preferences, they can request information from any table from the database.

I am using the below code snippet to query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM lecture_progress_table WHERE subject = :eSubject AND isWatched = :isWatched")
LiveData<List<LectureProgressObject>> getSubjectLectureProgress(String eSubject, int isWatched);
```

But instead of a pre-defined table name like "lecture_progress_table", I would like a situation where I can pass the table name dynamically to the query. Please, any assistant would be more than helpful.

Comment: Consider using [RawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/RawQuery)

Comment: Thanks, @sergiy. Please, if it's not too much to ask, can you help with a code snippet where a string is passed as a Table_name

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51911228/1806493)